# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',

Tags: ios, nsunknownkeyexception

I am sorry for posting this, but i am beyond fried and cant figure out whats wrong with this,  i am posting images, its a very simple app.

I am trying to have a reusable Prototype Cell.

I can't have Simple TableViewController, because i have to embed other things.

Here is my code, see if i am missing something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do a search on the error. This has been covered many, many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is pretty common when you delete an outlet from the .h/.m file but you leave the reference in the xib. It is saying that probably in the xib a label on the cell is linked to an outlet that doesn't exist anymore, in particular "labela".

Answer (score 0):

your label in the cell class is called sameen but in Xcode i can't see what its called. From the logs it seems to be looking for labela.

Recheck the outlet and connect to sameen